# Multiple Listeners on RxJava2 BehaviorSubject with Inconsistent Results

Tags: rx-java2

I have a BehaviorSubject that has three listeners that are subscribed prior to any emissions. I `.onNext()` two things: A followed by B.

Two of the listeners appropriately receive A and then B. But the third listener gets B, A. What could possibly explain this behavior? This is all on the same thread.

Here is some sample code (in Kotlin) that reproduces the results. Let me know if you need a Java version:

```
    @Test
    fun `rxjava test`() {
        val eventHistory1 = ArrayList<String>()
        val eventHistory2 = ArrayList<String>()
        val eventHistory3 = ArrayList<String>()

        val behaviorSubject = BehaviorSubject.create<String>()

        behaviorSubject.subscribe {
            eventHistory1.add(it)
        }

        behaviorSubject.subscribe {
            eventHistory2.add(it)
            if (it == "A") behaviorSubject.onNext("B")
        }

        behaviorSubject.subscribe {
            eventHistory3.add(it)
        }

        behaviorSubject.onNext("A")

        println(eventHistory1)
        println(eventHistory2)
        println(eventHistory3)

        assert(eventHistory1 == eventHistory2)
        assert(eventHistory2 == eventHistory3)
    }
```

And here is the output from the test:

```
[A, B]
[A, B]
[B, A]
```

Comment: There is no way to tell without seeing some of your code. Please post a code snippet demonstrating your setup and how you detect getting A or B.

Comment: Done! I should have mentioned earlier, but I am also calling `.onNext()` in one of the listener's subscribe blocks. Something tells me that is the root cause of the issue, but I don't understand why. All three listeners are technically subscribed prior to that `.onNext()`, yet one of the listeners receives the items in backwards order -- and it just so happens to be the listener that subscribed last.

Comment: Another interesting thing: if I delay the `.onNext()` in the aforementioned subscribe block, I can get consistent results for all three listeners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subjects are not re-entrant thus calling onNext on the same subject that is currently servicing onNexts is an undefined behavior. The [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html) warns about this case:

> Calling onNext(Object), onError(Throwable) and onComplete() is required to be serialized (called from the same thread or called non-overlappingly from different threads through external means of serialization). The Subject.toSerialized() method available to all Subjects provides such serialization **and also protects against reentrance (i.e., when a downstream Observer consuming this subject also wants to call onNext(Object) on this subject recursively)**.

In your particular case, signaling "B" happens first for the 3rd observer while it was about to signal "A" to it, hence the swapped order.

Use `toSerialized` on the subject to make sure this doesn't happen.

```
val behaviorSubject = BehaviorSubject.create<String>().toSerialized()
```